# Why do you think people may have different iris but their pupil are black and why when you push your eye at bottom you see two image?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, refraction, lenses, vision

[image]
Why do you think people my have different iris but their pupil are black?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but you see two images because you have two eyes. When you push your eye as shown in the photo, they are not "aligned" anymore and the images don't overlap (I think).

Comment: There are two unrelated questions in this question. It's better to stick to one question per question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about biology, not physics

Answer (score 1):

The pupils are black because they absorb all the light coming in with no reflections (visible, a doctor with a flashlight to see the interior does not see it black).

As Jonas said in the comments, you brain makes one image out of the two images coming from each eye. When you press you destroy the symmetry assumed in the brain calculations, and the images do not blend into one.

Comment: Pupils are simply holes formed by the iris, they don't have a color per se. It's likely because the intensity of all the light outside is much more than that of the interior of the eye...leading to that opening looking very dark/black.

Comment: @Triatticus isn;t that what I m saying?

Comment: Maybe, it sounded more like it's a physical object that absorbs light rather than a small "window" into a very small cavity. I suppose neither realistically changes the answer.